# curl_multi_exec: some images downloaded are missing some data / stream incomplete

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, curl-multi

I have implemented a PHP function which checks & downloads a lot of images (> 1'000) - as passed to it using an array - using the PHP `curl_multi_init()` method.

After reworking this a few times already, because I was getting things like 0 bytes files, etc. I have a solution now which downloads all images - BUT every other image file downloaded is not complete.

It looks to me as if I use `file_put_contents()` "too early", meaning, before some of the images' data has been received completely using `curl_multi_exec()`.

Unfortunately I didn't find any similar question nor any Google Results for my case, in which I need to use curl_multi_exec, but do NOT want to retrieve & save images using the curl-opt-header "`CURLOPT_FILE`".

**Hope someone is able to help me out regarding what I'm missing and why I get some broken images saved locally.**

## Here are some examples of the broken images retrieved:

[image: example image 1] [image: example image 2]

## Here's an example Array which I pass to my Multi-CURL-Function:

```
$curl_httpresources = [
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=mm&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/1_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=identicon&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/2_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=monsterid&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/3_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=wavatar&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/4_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=retro&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/5_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=mm&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/6_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=identicon&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/7_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=monsterid&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/8_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=wavatar&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/9_unsplash.jpg' ],
        [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=retro&r=x&s=427'
        ,'/srv/www/data/images/10_unsplash.jpg' ],
];
```

## My Multi-cURL PHP Function

Now for the function I'm currently using - and kind of "works", except some partially downloaded files - this is the code:

```
function cURLfetch(array $resources)
{
    /** Disable PHP timelimit, because this could take a while... */
    set_time_limit(0);

    /** Validate the $resources Array (not empty, null, or alike) */
    $resources_num = count($resources);
    if ( empty($resources) || $resources_num <= 0 ) return false;

    /** Callback-Function for writing data to file */
    $callback = function($resource, $filepath)
    {
        file_put_contents($filepath, $resource);
        /** For Debug only: output <img>-Tag with saved $resource */
        printf('<img src="%s"><br>', str_replace('/srv/www', '', $filepath));
    };

    /**
     * Initialize CURL process for handling multiple parallel requests 
     */
    $curl_instance = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_multi_exec_active = null;
    $curl_request_options = [
                                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'PHP-Script/1.0 (+https://website.com/)',
                                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
                                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
                                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                            ];

    /**
     * Looping through all $resources
     *   $resources[$i][0] = HTTP resource
     *   $resources[$i][1] = Target Filepath
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < $resources_num; $i++)
    {
        $curl_requests[$i] = curl_init($resources[$i][0]);
        curl_setopt_array($curl_requests[$i], $curl_request_options);
        curl_multi_add_handle($curl_instance, $curl_requests[$i]);
    }

    do {
        try {
            $curl_execute = curl_multi_exec($curl_instance, $curl_multi_exec_active);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    } while ($curl_execute == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);


    /** Wait until data arrives on all sockets */
    $h = 0; // initialise a counter
    while ($curl_multi_exec_active && $curl_execute == CURLM_OK)
    {
        if (curl_multi_select($curl_instance) != -1)
        {
            do {
              $curl_data = curl_multi_exec($curl_instance, $curl_multi_exec_active);
              $curl_done = curl_multi_info_read($curl_instance);
              /** Check if there is data... */
              if ($curl_done['handle'] !== NULL)
              {
                  /** Continue ONLY if HTTP statuscode was OK (200) */
                  $info = curl_getinfo($curl_done['handle']);
                  if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
                  {
                      if (!empty(curl_multi_getcontent($curl_requests[$h]))) {
                          /** Curl request successful. Process data using the callback function. */
                          $callback(curl_multi_getcontent($curl_requests[$h]), $resources[$h][1]);
                      }
                      $h++; // count up
                   }
               }
            } while ($curl_data == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }

    /** Close all $curl_requests */
    foreach($curl_requests as $request) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($curl_instance, $request);
    }
    curl_multi_close($curl_instance);

    return true;
}

/** Start fetching images from an Array */
cURLfetch($curl_httpresources);
```

### Thanks a lot for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: just a guess - you may be hitting the server too hard so at times it drops the connection (without emitting error). Loop and download simultaneously not more than 10 images. (Then try increasing...)

Comment: Thanks for the guess @Paolo. The interesting thing - which makes me feel against that theory - is, that ususally the first image is affected to be incomplete, and it happens already while only requesting a total of 10 images (see example Array in the initial question)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using just regular cURL requests in a classical loop, to query all >1'000 images and download the ones with a "HTTP 200 OK" response. My initial concerns, that the server might cut the connection due to a potential falsely identified DDoS has had no effect, why this approach works well for my case.

Here's the final function with regular cURL requests I'm using:

```
function cURLfetchUrl($url, $save_as_file)
{
    /** Validate $url & $save_as_file (not empty, null, or alike) */
    if ( empty($url) || is_numeric($url) ) return false;
    if ( empty($save_as_file) || is_numeric($save_as_file) ) return false;

    /** Disable PHP timelimit, because this could take a while... */
    set_time_limit(0);

    try {
        /**
         * Set cURL options to be passed to a single request
         */
        $curl_request_options = [
                                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'PHP-Script/1.0 (+https://website.com/)',
                                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
                                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                                ];

        /** Initialize & execute cURL-Request */
        $curl_instance = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($curl_instance, $curl_request_options);
        $curl_data = curl_exec($curl_instance);
        $curl_done = curl_getinfo($curl_instance);

        /** cURL request successful */
        if ($curl_done['http_code'] == 200)
        {
            /** Open a new file handle, write the file & close the file handle */
            if (file_put_contents($save_as_file, $curl_data) !== false) {
                // logging if file_put_contents was OK
            } else {
                // logging if file_put_contents FAILED
            }
        }

        /** Close the $curl_instance */
        curl_close($curl_instance);

        return true;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to execute it:

```
$curl_httpresources = [
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=mm&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/1_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=identicon&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/2_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=monsterid&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/3_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=wavatar&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/4_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=retro&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/5_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=mm&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/6_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=identicon&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/7_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=monsterid&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/8_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=wavatar&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/9_unsplash.jpg' ],
    [ 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/example?d=retro&r=x&s=427'
    ,'/srv/www/data/images/10_unsplash.jpg' ],
];

/** cURL all request from the $curl_httpresources Array */
if (count($curl_httpresources) > 0)
{
    foreach ($curl_httpresources as $resource)
    {
        cURLfetchUrl($resource[0], $resource[1]);
    }
}
```

Still, if someone has an idea, how to properly retrieve the file data streams using curl_multi, that would be great, as my answer to the initial question just shows a different approach - rather than solving the initial approach.